# How to detect the kernel size for Gaussian Blurring?

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am preprocessing an image to improve the results of tesseract. Therefore, I want to blur an image using OpenCV, so that OpenCV is able to detect shapes and therefore draw bounding boxes. However I am having problems setting the correct kernel size.

Below is an example of a document I currently work with. Please ignore the arrows and hand written words, since my documents are all written with a computer. [image: https://www.fernstudi.net/magazin/14117]

I have now read a few articles on the subject and also know by now that the kernel size specifies how many and which pixels in the environment of the target pixel should be considered.

However, I ask myself how to know how big this parameter should be. For example, the [OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html) simply chooses the value (5,5) - which seems pretty arbitrary to me. Also, it says that the kernel size must be positive and odd, but that's it.

Why is (5,5) chosen here and not, for example, (3,3) or (7,7)? And is it advisable to always use the same numbers or do you also take (1,3) or (5,3)? How do I know which is the 'best' kernel size, or how do I at least get a good initial value?

I would be very happy about your answers, many thanks in advance!

Comment: imho this depends on your tasks / images / goals. A gaussian filter is a low pass filter, so if you know enough about your signal, e.g. what kind of high frequency noise there is, you can choose the filter exactly to your needs. But typically you dont, so you might have to get a feeling for your data, gain experience with filters and data, etc.. Why do you WANT to use a gaussian filter at all? Maybe you can compare it to using sandpaper on a wooden surface in order to improve the surface for glueing. It's probably hard to define which kind of sandpaper-strength to use for what kind of wood.

Comment: you tag your question with `tesseract` but don't refer to any of that in your post. you criticize arbitrary and unexplained choices of values, yet your post contains no specific situation to discuss, or pictures, or anything to go by. -- please edit your post and present your problem.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. I am about to preprocess a document for tesseract, therefore I want to apply blurring to detect shapes and create bounding boxes. However, since the documents I work with are quite sensitive, I can't provide you with an example image, unfortunately.

To be honest, I apply Gaussian Blurring since it is used in the papers and tutorials I previously read. Also, according to the OpenCV documentation, it seems to fit to my specific task, therefore i use it. However, if there are other fitting blurring functions, I would also consider them.

Comment: related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_layout_analysis

Answer (score 3):

When using the Gaussian Blur there are some things to play with. The standard deviation/variance and the radius/kernel size.

The standard deviation for a two-dimensional kernel is the radius in pixels containing 68% of the integrated magnitude of the coefficients. Increasing the standard deviation will increase the effective kernel size.

The size of the kernel should normally be selected large enough so that the kernel coefficients of the border rows and columns contribute very little to the sum of coefficients. By selecting a kernel size parameters six times the standard deviation the border parameters will be 1% or lower than the center parameter.

In opencv, the function `cv2.GaussianBlur(src, ksize, sigmaX, sigmaY, borderType)` allows you to play not only with the kernel size but with the standard deviation of each axis.

Unfortunately, the choice of the standard variation and kernel size of your gaussian filter is extremely application dependent. So, there is no absolute truth. However, typically, you want to choose a gaussian filter such that you are considerable amount of high frequency components in your image.

You could provide an example image with which you are working with.

Hope it works.

Info from:
[Link1](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10057/gaussian-blur-standard-deviation-radius-and-kernel-size)
[Link2](http://www.imagemet.com/WebHelp6/Default.htm#ImFilter/Smoothing_Gaussian.htm)

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailled answer. It really helped to get a better understanding of the further parameters!

I added some edits in the inital post and provided you with an example, so that you can get a better understanding of my task.

Comment: So, your task is to detect the gray boxes of the image or the texts?

Comment: Kind of! Since this document has a tabular structure, tesseract has problems reading it. Therefore I want to draw bounding boxes around the words, to clearly specify the ROI.

Comment: I am not sure if I would use Gaussian Blur first. But if your goal is to detect a ROI, an easy approach could be: (1) Threshold the image (gray level OTSU, HSV color space...)  (2) Find all the connected components (3) Process the connected components to skip false positives and (4) Obtain BBox for each connected component. It is hard to solve a problem without seeing a real example, but I hope it works for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advise! However, I just found another solution. I couldn't find the right contours since I've set a 'wrong' parameter in the contourFind function. After I've changed it, drawing the boxes worked. Therefore the error wasn't caused by my blurring.
Anyway, thank you very much for your support! Stay safe!

Comment: You're welcome mate! Nice to hear that!